# How do I get my VirtualBox to load into the system I already installed?

Tags: installation, virtualbox, macosx, xubuntu

I am trying to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox on my Mac OS X. I got through the whole installation process with out any problems. But, when it asked to restart the computer and it rebooted, it keeps asking to start the installation. At first, I thought this meant that the installation didn't work, but when while I began re-installing it asked if I wanted to install the new system alongside the old Ubuntu system that I had just installed.

How do I get my VirtualBox to load into the system I already installed? It just seems to only allow me to install again, but nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Seems the the installation ISO/CD is still attached to the Virtual Machine and it is still booting from it.

Check your virtual machine settings and unlink the CD/ISO image.

Comment: Open your VM > Devices > CD/DVD Devices > Remove Disk from virtual drive